# python: how can i avoid " list index out of range" in this simple while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

my L1 array contains numbers like 0.029999999999999999 which i want to print off as 0.03

my code works, but gives an error at the end because the last count is out of range. i understand why it breaks, but dont know how to fix it. thanks

```
count = 1

while L1:
    print "%.2f" %L1[count]
    count = count + 1
```

Comment: thanks, but its slightly more complex in that i want to create a new array that contains the rounded numbers, im at a bit of a loss of how to do that without a counter, which is usually how i do it

Comment: Your while condition should check L1[count], not just L1. The truth value of L1 never changes.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to print all numbers in `L1`, use:

```
for x in L1: print '%.2f' % x
```

If you want to skip the first one, `for x in L1[1:]:` will work.

**Edit**: the OP mentions in a comment (!) that their desire is actually to "create a new array" (I imagine they actually mean "a new list", not an `array.array`, but that wouldn't be very different). There are no "rounded numbers" in the float world -- you can use `round(x, 2)`, but that will still give you a float, so it won't necessarily have "exactly 2 digits".  Anyway, for a list of strings:

```
newlistofstrings = ['%.2f' % x for x in L1]
```

or for one with decimal numbers (which **can** have exactly 2 digits, if you want):

```
import decimal
newlistofnnumbers = [decimal.Decimal('%.2f') % x for x in L1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just loop through the `L1` list instead of doing a while loop?

```
for i in L1:
   print "%.2f" % i
```

Keep it simple :)

Answer (score 0):

```
L2=["%.2f" %i for i in L1]
```

Answer (score 0):

2 problems:

1. Your loop never ends (while L1)
2. You start indexing with 1 (count = 1 in initialisation)

Better is, like the others said:

```
for i in L1:
    print "%.2f" % i
```

and if you also need the index (count):

```
for (index, item) in enumerate(L1):
    print "Element number (0-based) %d is %f" % (index, item)
```

See also [Pythonic expressions](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html) for some more nice ways to use python.